# Pygame not reading input

Tags: python, pygame

I have a `Paddle` class with a `move` method that reads some keyboard input:

```
def move(self, dt):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]: return -self.speed * dt
    elif keys[K_RIGHT]: return  self.speed * dt
    return 0
```

The same class is used in another program and it works fine there. I simply have no idea why this is happening. What's really weird is that when the program is run from Eclipse or IDLE the keypresses are detected, but when run directly from the file nothing happens. Also, I recently added code that makes the ball wait some time before moving and it does in Eclipse, but does not when run directly from the .py file.

```
def update(self, dt):
    if self.on_paddle:
        self.rect.centerx = self.paddle.rect.centerx
        self.time_passed += dt
        if self.time_passed > 3:
            self.on_paddle = False
        else:
            self.rect = self.calcnewpos(dt)
            self.handle_collision()
```

Why is this happening? And why it works when run from eclipse but not from the file? [Here](http://codepad.org/R2bBJhNz) is the main stuff.

**UPDATE**

1. I realized that my `game.py` file, which is the main file (the one that is run), automatically creates *.pyc* files for all imported modules. But in another game (which also has an `objects.py` file with a `Ball` and `Paddle` classes), no *.pyc* files are generated and the events checked in the update method of Paddle there are correctly handled.
2. I tried deleting all *.pyc* files and adding `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` to prevent them from being automatically generated but that also didn't helped. Though the *.pyc* files no longer show up the program is stil behaving the same way it did before.
3. Idea: Could it be that I am shadowing a module with a pygame or built-in module of the same name? Or the other way around? Up till now I have the following modules in the project folder:

   `constants.py`

   `frame.py`

   `game.py`

   `helper.py`

   `level.py`

   `menu.py`

   `music.py`

   `objects.py`

   `stats.py`

   `text.py`

   `vec2d.py`

Comment: What do you mean by "run directly from the file?"

Comment: Just running the .py file.

Comment: Do you have a call to `pygame.init` among the executed code in that .py file?

Comment: Yeah, inside a *main* function in the outer scope.

Comment: I would start debugging this by narrowing it down.  If you use `pygame.event.get` instead, do the key press/release events come through there?  Also, what startup and initialization code is present in the other programs that is not present in yours?

Comment: `pygame.event.get` is in the main loop and the events it gets are correctly handled. Only the events checked by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` in the `Paddle` class are not read. What do you mean by *startup and initialization code*?

Comment: So are you getting these input events via `pygame.event.get`, at the same time that you are not getting them via `pygame.key.get_pressed`?  Startup and initialization code is any code the runs prior to the start of the main game loop.

Comment: Yeah, if I press ESC `pygame.event.get` handles it and exits the program. But if I press the left or right arrow keys, nothing happens. I added the code to the post so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Try printing something in the `move` function, just to test if it's actually listening or not.

Comment: Maybe you changed some file names or moved some files and when you run the python file directly you run *another* file than eclipse does or some compiled python files are run instead (*.pyc files). Try searching and deleting all *.pyc files before running your main python file.

Comment: Tried it several times but it didn't worked. I noticed that this file automatically creates .pyc files for all imported modules before running, but in my other game, where I also have an `objects.py` file with a `Ball` and `Paddle` classes, it doesn't generate any .pyc files. Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was quite a embarrassing one. In the mainloop for the game I was calculating `dt` (time passed since the last) like this:

```
dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
```

So it was truncating to 0 because the value returned by `clock.tick` is a float and because the paddle and the ball need `dt`, they just woudn't move. I still don't understand why `dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000` worked fine in my other game though.

Comment: @DominicKexel Don't understand that either.